# jquery document wont work when using window

Tags: jquery

I have using jquery to go to url but why wont jquery go to the url?
    jQuery.document(window.document).insert("jQuery.document(window.document).location='/''));

Comment: window.location='/';

Comment: I honestly dont understand what you are trying to do with jQuery, but you are trying to use a function which doesnt exist